Merge Feature Breaks Texture. Another fix?
So, I have an object that was already textured that I needed to rig. The bones work fine, however the model has un-joined edges causing it the break the mesh. At first I tried to use the Merge by Distance feature but that just breaks my texture entirely. Is there another way to merge the edges without breaking the texture.

Hello it's hard to understand could you please share your file?

Here is the blend file. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/j6rcsnq2r7jxia5ohgmx6/ElephantPet.blend?rlkey=vmhaua8a6xu67ycq6b7427qky&st=tvzuys2k&dl=0

it's not clear how you want to do the trunk, you have floating faces and holes, also maybe you should do it straight as default pose? The texture is not complicated, it will be easy to correct if you ever change the topology

I want to patch the floating faces. I normally use the merge feature which does fix my gap issue, but that breaks my texture. I unfortunately didn't get a choice on the Model, I was provided it and have to work with it the way it is.

i don't think that there's any magic trick, you need to fix the topology then unwrap the trunk again and put the islands correctly over the map
